# using php and imap to read exchange 2010 mail

Tags: php, imap, exchange-server

We have a mailbox set up on our exchange server with multiple aliases. The php script then loops through, looks at which alias the mail was sent to and determines the action to take.

This all worked fine with exchange 2003 but we have recently upgraded our system to exchange 2010 and suddenly the php imap data is telling me that the address it is sent to is always the default regardless of where it was actually sent.

When opening the email through outlook the properties show the valid "to" address. Below is outlook and PHP (imap_fetchheader)

**Outlook**

```
Received: from server ([server]) by
 server ([server]) with mapi id
 14.02.0247.003; Thu, 24 Jan 2013 16:17:21 +0000
Content-Type: application/ms-tnef; name="winmail.dat"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
From: My Name<me@domain.com>
To: Mailbox <scanned.workshop@domain.com>
Subject: -
Thread-Topic: --
Thread-Index: Ac36TYTyAEX3VodpSxiOpceRNCRERwAAMALg
Date: Thu, 24 Jan 2013 16:17:19 +0000
Message-ID: <99BC329D02E8D84C8FB1A96C34B4ADDC1900E7@server>
Accept-Language: en-GB, en-US
Content-Language: en-US
X-MS-Has-Attach: yes
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: -1
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator: <99BC329D02E8D84C8FB1A96C34B4ADDC1900E7@server>
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource: server
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Internal
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthMechanism: 04
X-Originating-IP: [192.168.110.40]
```

**PHP**

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Received: from server ([server]) by
 server ([server]) with mapi id
 14.02.0247.003; Thu, 24 Jan 2013 16:17:21 +0000
From: Me <me@domain.com>
To: Mailbox <scanned@domain.com>
Subject: -
Thread-Topic: -
Thread-Index: Ac36TYTyAEX3VodpSxiOpceRNCRERwAAMALg
Date: Thu, 24 Jan 2013 16:17:19 +0000
Message-ID: <99BC329D02E8D84C8FB1A96C34B4ADDC1900E7@server>
Accept-Language: en-GB, en-US
Content-Language: en-US
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Internal
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthMechanism: 04
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource: xxxxx
X-MS-Has-Attach: yes
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: -1
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator:
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
        boundary="_002_99BC329D02E8D84C8FB1A96C34B4ADDC1900E7WINSERV12lewisloc_"
```

the content coming through is valid but for some reason since the upgrade only the default mailbox is showing to php and not the alias the email was sent to.

Any ideas or is this one for the server guys?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way around this problem so thought i would post it for others if they have a similar problem.

Rather than using an alias on the main account as worked with legacy exchange I built a distribution group and added the account as the only member.

When php looked up the "to" address it then came through correctly